# Tangle babel code to specific location in source file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming, tangle

Let's say I'm creating many babel code blocks in a growing org-mode buffer and I'm tangling them all to a single file. However, I want certain blocks to appear above others. For example,

```
#+begin_src haskell :eval never :exports code :tangle fp41.hs
module FP41 where
import Data.List
#+end_src

#+begin_src haskell :eval never :exports code :tangle fp41.hs
data Mood = Blah | Woot deriving (Show, Eq)

changeMood Blah = Woot
changeMood _ = Blah
#+end_src
```

This works wonderfully, but I always have to watch what order the blocks are int to avoid spaghetti code. So what if I want to add another `import` way down in the buffer

```
#+begin_src haskell :eval never :exports code :tangle fp41.hs
import GHC.Int
#+end_src
```

but not have it below regular code in the tangled file? That is, I want it going to the `header` block in the tangled code file `fp41.hs`, grouped/following the previous last `import`. I could tangle them to separate files -- one for "header" stuff, one for code. If that's the route, is there any way then to automate combining them into a single file?

Comment: I think they get tangled in sequence: I don't know of any way to change that. But  I think you can use [Noweb](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html#Noweb-Reference-Syntax).

Comment: As usual, thanks for the tip. noweb will work, although it requires my top source block containing the module info to refer to the desired named blocks below, i.e., the process isn't fire and forget.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an exact solution, but the next-best thing would be something like this

```
* Test
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :noweb-sep "\n\n"
:END:

#+begin_src haskell :eval never :tangle nowebtest.hs :noweb yes
module FP41 where
import Data.List
<<ghcInt-imp>>
<<mood>>
#+end_src

#+name: mood
#+begin_src haskell :eval never

data Mood = Blah | Woot deriving (Show, Eq)

changeMood Blah = Woot
changeMood _ = Blah
#+end_src

#+name: ghcInt-imp
#+begin_src haskell :eval never
import GHC.Int
#+end_src
```

following the noweb docs [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html#Noweb-Reference-Syntax). This produces what's needed

```
module FP41 where
import Data.List
import GHC.Int

data Mood = Blah | Woot deriving (Show, Eq)

changeMood Blah = Woot
changeMood _ = Blah
```

although that `:noweb-sep` doesn't seem to work and I don't find anything on it other than it's mention.